# Why .NET uses reference type inside struct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am working on Blazor project, and I am using Virtualization component. I don't have any issue, but just trying to understand one thing.

I found that in `Virtualization` component there is `ItemsProvider` which returns [`ItemsProviderResult<TItem>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.virtualization.itemsproviderresult-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0). It is Value type, but has a property `Items` which is collection of reference types.

And here are my questions:

- If we lose a scope of `ItemsProviderResult<TItem>` will reference to `Items` be left in memory or it will be removed?
- How could I benchmark `Struct vs Class` performance differences in this particular case?
- What do you think, why Blazor has done so?

I have googled general information about `Value` and `Reference` types. I found information about that struct is recommended to be always immutable. But I haven't found an answer for question what happens with `Reference` type object if `struct` loses scope.

**UPD1:**

I understand that the collection of reference type and any other reference type property will be released from memory by GC, but will it be at the same time when struct lose scope or it will be staying in memory until GC will remove it?

Comment: `If we lose a scope of ItemsProviderResult<TItem> will reference to Items be left in memory or it will be removed?` The Garbage Collector will clear up all items that are no longer reachable from a GC root.

Comment: What would you want to benchmark? How a potential ItemsProviderResult implementationas class would be behave compared to the actual struct implementation?

Comment: The main point of garbage collection is that *it's the GCs job to work out when objects are unreachable and can be reclaimed*. You don't have to help it out.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I understand that the collection of reference type and any other reference type property will be released from memory by GC, but will it be at the same time when struct lose scope or it will be staying in memory until GC will remove it?

Comment: There's no guarantee when it will be freed, per se. But by the fact that it's unreachable, there shouldn't be anything that you can do in your code that *would be affected by when it's reclaimed*

Comment: You may also want to read Raymond Chen's [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203): "Garbage collection is *simulating a computer with an infinite amount of memory*. The rest is mechanism."

Comment: @AleksandrStepanov At no point does `ItemsProviderResult<TItem>` create ANY object, let alone create one on the heap. Instances of this struct live on the heap and do not require garbage collection. The data they are wrapping *may* live on the heap, but that would be a very poor reason to force `ItemsProviderResult<TItem>` to live on the heap as well.

Comment: To be clear: When a method with an `ItemsProviderResult<TItem>` parameter returns, the entire instance of the `ItemsProviderResult<TItem>` parameter will be removed from the stack which means that the `Items` reference that it contains will ALSO be removed from the stack.

Comment: @MatthewWatson OK, reference gets removed when the `struct` gets removed. But `Items` itself keeps living in the heap, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value types will either be stored in the stack, or on the heap as part of an reference object [*]. Because of this value types are typically cheaper. If they are stored on the stack they will be handled automatically by the stack. If they are part on an object they will be collected as part of that object, the garbage collector does not need to do any extra work to keep track of it.

In contrast, reference types will always be stored on the heap. They will also need some extra memory for the GC to use for tracking and marking objects.

In some sense, value types is just a way to avoid listing multiple parameters. They might as well not exist at all as far as the garbage collector is concerned. A struct holding a reference going out of scope will be handled exactly the same as the reference itself going out of scope. I.e. the GC will collect the referenced object when it gets around to it. Assuming there are no other references.

In general, value types are preferred for small, immutable, types. While reference types are preferred for larger types, or if mutation of the value is needed. But whenever you think about performance, [consider](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil):

> There is no doubt that the grail of efficiency leads to abuse. Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.
>
> Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

I.e. it probably does not matter unless you have many thousands of objects.

Library authors need to be more careful, since they do not know how their library is used. And they cannot really change their mind if they realize they made a incorrect mistake, since that might break the code for thousands of users.

[*] Technically, stack/heap are implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

As for the `How could I benchmark Struct vs Class performance differences in this particular case?`.

Benchmark methodology is below, idea is to simulate Virtualization scenario.

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class GridItemsProviderResultTest
{
    record class Model( string Name, string Description );

    int dataCount = 5000;
    int requestSize = 20;
    ICollection<Model> itemsList = new List<Model>();
    
    public DataSourceResultTest()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++ )
        {
            itemsList.Add( new Model( i + " name " + i, i + " description " + i ) );
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    [Benchmark]
    public void VirtualizedRows()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < dataCount; i += requestSize )
        {
            GridItemsProviderRequest<Model> request = new( i, requestSize, null, false, default );
            IQueryable<Model> data = itemsList.AsQueryable()
                .Skip( request.StartIndex )
                .Take( request.Count.Value );
            GridItemsProviderResult<Model> items = GridItemsProviderResult.From( data.ToArray(), data.Count() );

            Assert.True( items.Data.Count == requestSize );
        }
    }
}
```

Benchmark results.

GridItemsProviderResult is struct, TGridItem is class

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VirtualizedRows | 74.71 ms | 0.181 ms | 0.160 ms | 714.2857 | 285.7143 | 5.96 MB |

GridItemsProviderResult is class, TGridItem is class

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VirtualizedRows | 74.63 ms | 0.221 ms | 0.206 ms | 714.2857 | 285.7143 | 5.97 MB |

GridItemsProviderResult is struct, TGridItem is struct

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VirtualizedRows | 71.90 ms | 0.324 ms | 0.303 ms | 714.2857 | 285.7143 | 5.95 MB |

GridItemsProviderResult is class, TGridItem is struct

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VirtualizedRows | 71.83 ms | 0.400 ms | 0.354 ms | 714.2857 | 285.7143 | 5.96 MB |

Answer (score 1):

> If we lose a scope of `ItemsProviderResult<TItem>` will reference to
> `Items` be left in memory or it will be removed?

In C#, if something goes out of scope it will eventually be released from memory.

So for `Items`, it will become eligible for garbage collection when there are no more references to the struct that contains it or `Items` itself. `Items` will remain in memory until released by the garbage collector.

> How could I benchmark `Struct vs Class` performance differences in this
> particular case?

You can make use of the Benchmark.NET library for testing methods that perform the desired operations using structs/classes.

> What do you think, why Blazor has done so?

`Items` will be a collection of whatever `TItem` is.

If `TItem` is a reference type, the you will have a collection of reference types.

If `TItem` is a value type, the you will have a collection of value types.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I still don't get it. I understand that the collection of reference type and any other reference type property will be released from memory by GC, but will it be at the same time when struct lose scope or it will be staying in memory until GC will remove it? And why do blazor devs use `readonly struct` instead of a `class` if there is possible mutable reference type property inside?

Comment: `And why do blazor devs use readonly struct instead of a class if there is possible mutable reference type property inside?` Because then it would increase memory pressure unnecessarily, since now the `ItemsProviderResult<TItem>` will have to live on the heap rather than the stack.

Comment: @MatthewWatson what about `Items` inside it then if it is collection of `Reference` types? Does it also live on the stack if `ItemsProviderResult<TItem>` is a `struct`?

Comment: @AleksandrStepanov No it doesn't, but that's no reason to force `ItemsProviderResult<TItem>`  to also live on the stack.